# Still getting __pycache__ folder even after adding export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

Tags: python

I added to my .bashrc file in the first line

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

but when I run a python program **pycache** still generates.

Comment: Is this all in the same session? Have you reloaded your .bashrc file with `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: How are you running the Python program? That should work for Python programs you run in the shell, but `.bashrc` won’t affect daemons e.g. supervisord running Flask or Django

Comment: I run my program in the terminal of a local Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Open a new terminal and try again.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times, still the same result :(